# group by in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following order table:

```
| id | user_id | order_date |
| 1  | 5       | 24/03/2014 |
| 2  | 5       | 25/02/2014 |
| 3  | 6       | 25/06/2014 |
```

I would like a query that returns me the max order_date for each user of my table. In my example, the result would be:

```
| id | user_id | order_date |
| 1  | 5       | 24/03/2014 |
| 3  | 6       | 25/06/2014 |
```

I tried the following query:

```
select user_id, id, max(order_date) 
from order
GROUP BY cmd_user_id;
```

But this code generates the following error: column "order.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

I don't know what to do here. Can someone help me please?

I feel that I need a group by because this is the beginning of my query. I would like, afterward to add some extra condition to select the orders (for instance the order paid by a specific payment mode and during the past 10 days but I will always be interested in the max date of the past 10 days).

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Simply remove the `id` column from your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select user_id, id, max(order_date) from order GROUP BY cmd_user_id;
```

The field in the select and the group by doesn't match but I will suppose that user_id and cmd_user_id are the same field and it's a typo.
Anyway, if you are using group by, the fields in the select part must have an aggregate function, like max(order_date), or must be included in the group by fields like cmd_user_id.
Like Kouber says, remove the id field from the select part, use an aggregate function on it or include it in the group by fields.